# Twitter bootstrap js getting blocked by Same Origin Policy, but non-bootstrap isn't. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been attempting to put together a website that requires obtaining xml data from another website.  So far, using only html and javascript (no twitter bootstrap), I can access the website XML and populate a select dropdown menu.  Here is the non-bootstrap html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getXML.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Test App</h1>
    <button id="button1">submit</button>
    <select id="selectState"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the bootstrap html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- jQuery and JavaScript files -->    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getXML.js"></script> 
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
  </head>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4 col-xs-3">
            <form class = "well">
                <h2 class="page-header">Inputs</h2>
                    <label class="control-label" for="selectState">Select State:</label>
                    <select id="selectState"></select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="button1" >submit</button>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

and here is the getXML.js script:

```
var HttpClient = function() {
    this.get = function(aUrl, aCallback) {
        anHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        anHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (anHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && anHttpRequest.status == 200)
                aCallback(anHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
        anHttpRequest.open( "GET", aUrl, true );            
        anHttpRequest.send( null );
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#button1" ).click(function () {         
        aClient = new HttpClient();
        aClient.get('http://www.waterqualitydata.us/Station/search?characteristicName=Caffeine&mimeType=xml&bBox=-92.8,44.2,-88.9,46', function(data) {

            xmlDoc = $.parseXML( data ),
            $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
            $LocName = $xml.find( "MonitoringLocationName" );

            var arr = [];
            $.each($LocName,function() {
                arr.push( $(this).text() );
            });

            for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 1 ) { 
                $('#selectState').append('<option>'+arr[i]+'</option>');
            }

            alert( "success" );

        });
    });
});
```

Now, when I try and using the Twitter bootstrap html, I am getting a Cross-Origin Request Block due to the Same Origin Policy.

Is there any reason why the scripts that don't use Twitter Bootstrap can get around the SOP, while the twitter bootstrap version can't?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Bootstrap script to include the '`type'` attribute, like so:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The 'type' parameter here is key - it is what allows the remote request to happen. CSS and JS are allowed to do this kind of cross domain linking, as it is judged by the W3C gods to be a low security risk (at least last I checked).

Check these links out for more information on CORS:

- IE's explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- Mozilla's thoughts: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't seem to do the trick.  I'm still getting a Cross-Origin Request Block when I check the console of the Firefox debugger.  Any other suggestions?  This seems like pretty weird behavior to me!

Comment: I'd add elements from your second HTML snippet to your first one until you figure out which thing is creating the issue. Meta stuff, bootstrap CSS, then bootstrap script. But none of these assets are remote. So maybe its in your JS call after all...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found the problem.  I was placing the `<button>` inside a `<form>` element.  This apparently raises the SOP block.  Without the `<form>` element, no SOP block was raised.

I haven't looked at the exact reason behind this, but maybe its related to a security feature baked into the `<form>` element, since `<form>` elements can be used to pass sensitive information (passwords, etc.)?